# SQL Finding duplicates records per user

Tags: sql, sql-server

So if I have a table as follows

with column

```
date       datetime
employee   varchar
```

and I want to find all the records where a particular user has the same date more than once

and for each duplicate found I would need

```
date    employee    numDuplicates
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `GROUP BY` with `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT employee, [date], Count(*) As numDuplicates
FROM Table
GROUP BY employee, [date]
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

In the event that you are storing a date and time in the datetime field, then you need to extract the date to do the group by.  In SQL Server 2008 and onward, you can do:

```
select employee, cast([date] as date), count(*) as numDuplicates
from t
group by employee, cast([date] as date)
having count(*) > 1
```